# TPL Dataflow how to remove the link between the blocks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I would like to know. How can I remove the link between the blocks? In other words. I want to get opposite of LinkTo.

I want to write a logger based on tlp dataflow.

I wrote this interface and want to delete a subscription for ILogListener when it needed.

```
public interface ILogManager
{
    void RemoveListener(ILogListener listener);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you link blocks:

```
var link = someSourceBlock.LinkTo(someTargetBlock);
```

you get a return value that implements `IDisposable`.

To kill the link, just dispose of that return value:

```
link.Dispose();
```

See the [`.LinkTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462706%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation (in particular the section about the return statement):

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.IDisposable
>
> An IDisposable that, upon calling Dispose, will unlink the source from the target.